# How to exclude Firebase Messaging from Unity iOS builds, but not Android builds

Tags: android, ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, push-notification

I have a Unity project that builds for both Android and iOS. I want to integrate Firebase on my Android builds, but not for my iOS builds.

Is there a way to exclude Firebase Messaging from the iOS builds completely, but keep it in for Android?

I don't see the options to do so in the Firebase settings panel.

I tried to unselect the Editor/iOS parts of the unity package when installing it, but I still get linker errors (when building my iOS app in Xcode) that reference missing Firebase directories.

Thanks in advance,
- cg

Comment: I desperately need an answer to that too 